# Fused Location Provider Client cannot resolve in android studio

Tags: android

I was trying to use Fused Location Provider Client class but android studio cannot recognize it although I have version 3.2 and I downloaded all updates

The error

[image]

the code

```
package com.example.amr.googleplaces;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MapActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Map is ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG,"Map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;


    }
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION= Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getLocationPermission();
    }
    private void getDeviceLocation()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"getting the device location");

    }
    private void initMap()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFrafment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrafment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }
    private void getLocationPermission()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"get location permission");
        String[] permissions = {FINE_LOCATION,COARSE_LOCATION};
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),COARSE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();

            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult called");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 )
                {
                    for (int i = 0 ; i< grantResults.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG,"permission failed");
                           return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult :permission granted");

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    initMap();
                }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: @Amr Hassan please show your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

have you included it in gradle with the latest version whatever it is

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Below dependencies in your **build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

---

If you're not using latest gradle version use below:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

> **Note :** To see the current breakdown of individual APIs, take a look at the
>   documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

you also need to import it on your page if it's in your manifest.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
```